# Как удалить gccgo компилятор с linux-mint?

Tags: golang, gcc, linux-mint

Случайно установил 2 компилятора go. Один из них gccgo, теперь при компиляции кода на го автоматически используется gccgo. Я удалил gccgo с помощью команды remove, но при вводе команды sudo go version все равно показывает, что используется компилятор gccgo, как его удалить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте удалить пакет gccgo-go [sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove gccgo-go](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/utopic/gccgo-go?action=remove)

Comment: Если и это не поможет, тогда можно вместо `gccgo-go` попробовать написать `gccgo*`

Comment: @zed, спасибо, это помогло

Comment: Что конкретно помогло? `gccgo-go` или вариант со звёздочкой?

Comment: @zed,помогло gccgo-go